# How to increase the width of a particular node of a hierarchy in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a hierarchy layout as shown in the image below where the 3rd layer of nodes contains words that are quite long so I want to give these nodes more space to their left to make it easier to read. But I am not sure what to change to do so.

[image]

Code for the node, path and the text:

```
    const root = hierarchy(investmentByLocationData).sort(
      (a, b) =>
        descending(a.height, b.height) || ascending(a.data.name, b.data.name)
    );

    root.dx = 12;
    root.dy = width / (root.height + 1);
    cluster().nodeSize([root.dx, root.dy])(root);

    const linkGenerator = linkHorizontal()
      .x((node) => node.y)
      .y((node) => node.x);

    svg
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .join((enter) =>
        enter
          .append("circle")
          .attr("fill", (d) => (d.children ? "#555" : "#999"))
      )
      .attr("r", 2.5)
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", (node) => node.y)
      .attr("cy", (node) => node.x)
      .attr("r", 2.5)
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .delay((node) => node.depth * 300)
      .attr("opacity", 1);

    // links
    const enteringAndUpdatingLinks = svg
      .selectAll(".path")
      .data(root.links())
      .join("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", linkGenerator)
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", function() {
        const length = this.getTotalLength();
        return `${length} ${length}`;
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.4);

    if (data !== previouslyRenderedData) {
      enteringAndUpdatingLinks
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", function() {
          return this.getTotalLength();
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .delay((link) => link.source.depth * 500)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 5);
    }

    //labels
    svg
      .selectAll(".text")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .join("text")
      .attr("x", (d) => d.y)
      .attr("y", (d) => d.x)
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("dx", (d) => (d.children ? -6 : 6))
      .text((d) => (d.children ? d.data.name : d.data.funding))
      .attr("text-anchor", (d) => (d.children ? "end" : "start"))
      .attr("font-size", (d) => (d.children ? 15 : 14));
```

Comment: So you want to push 'Goverment-led and Private' a bit further to the left correct? I guess you could just select the nodes and add a transform attribute, or may be see if you can push the Country labels to the right?

Comment: No I want the child nodes of "Goverment-led and Private" to be pushed to the right. Would I be able to select the nodes by the index in this case?

Comment: I see, you can always inspect the svg from DOM and see how its build, ideally you want to add a class name those specific nodes and select them easily like that, if not you can always drill down the svg code and graben them

Comment: Please turn your code into a runnable snippet or fiddle, with some sample data if possible

Comment: @RubenHelsloot sure I will do that, give me a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tinkering around with it I managed to solve it by altering `root.dx` and `root.dy`.

```
root.dx = 18;
root.dy = width / (root.height * 0.6);
```